# Is there any way to use Windows localization data in your own applications?

Tags: windows, localization, internationalization

For example, in my case I would like to get localized strings for music file tags you could see in explorer file description (see red underline here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NhZQ.jpg).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`IPropertyDescription::GetDisplayName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method appears to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is placed in the resource file (you can use file searching mechanism to find the right one), so the answer for technical possibility is yes. However, on the legal front I would not be so sure. This is something that surely is copyrighted (although I cannot tell if [Softword](http://softword.pl/) or Microsoft (probably the latter) is the copyright holder).

Anyway, maybe you can find what you are looking for in freely available [Amarok Polish translation](https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/dapper/+source/amarok/+pots/amarok/pl/+translate?start=0&batch=10&show=all&field.alternative_language=&field.alternative_language-empty-marker=1).

Comment: It's not really the point. Well it is, but it's not only about single english-polish translation, I'm trying to create shell extension so I don't want to be bothered by translating tag names to eh... how many language versions of Windows there are, I would prefer to use existing translations. Not only it would save me some work, but also help to keep it coherent with rest of the shell.

Comment: Legal issues aside, the problem is that these resources are implementation details of Windows Explorer and subject to change at any time.  Granted Microsoft probably doesn't recycle resource IDs very often, but relying on them is a recipe for failure.  If there is not some public API to look these strings up (there very well could be) then you should really provide your own resources.

Comment: The public API is `IPropertyDescription::GetDisplayName`.